# How comparable are the "Law School Legends" series of audiobook-on-CD to 1L and 2L lectures of the same course name?

Tags: united-states, legal-education

In particular, I have in mind Freer's *Civil Procedure* title. It consists of about 10 hours or so. However, most of the syllabi I can find for Civil Procedure indicate 20+ scheduled classes for this course.

Granted, not all of these will be lectures, there are exams and other instructional methods. It seems reasonable that 10 hours of audio might be roughly equivalent to the lectures one would experience in that course.

On the other hand, having listened to the intro and briefly glanced at the track listing... and it has a Cliff Notes-ish feel to it.

Can someone who has both sat through a full semester of Civil Procedure lectures and listened to this title briefly compare the two and explain what might be missing?